# Store data from for loop in matrix - keep getting error

Tags: matlab

Sorry, I know this question has been asked a lot and I have looked at those answers but I still can't solve my problem and I'm getting the following error:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

Here is my code:

```
for i = 0:10, 

    x1 = rand(1);
    x2 = rand(1);
    x = [x1 x2];

Y(i,:) = [x(1) x(2)]
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab indexing starts at 1, not 0 as in some other languages. So in the first iteration of your loop, you have `i=0`, but you can't do `y(0,:)`. With the code you have posted, just do `for i=1:11` to get 11 iterations. (Alternatively, you could just do `rand(11,2)` if the only goal of the code is to generate the matrix.)